# react-helmet mixing fields during renderStatic

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I'm running server-side render of the React application. I'm using `express` for this purposes. The whole server-side render code looks like this:

```js
import * as React from "react"
import * as ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server"
import * as express from "express"
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import walker = require("react-tree-walker")
import { useStaticRendering } from "mobx-react"

import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import Provider from "../src/Provider"
import { StaticRouterContext } from "react-router"
import version = require("../version")

var _template: string = require(`../dist/${version.v()}/index.html`)

interface IRenderResponse {
    statusCode: number,
    template: string,
    redirect?: string
}

const run = (url: string, locale?: string): Promise<IRenderResponse> => {
    var template: string
    var html: string = ""
    var head: object
    var context: StaticRouterContext = {}

    useStaticRendering(true)

    var routing = (
        <StaticRouter 
            location={url} 
            context={context}
        >
            <Provider defaultLocale={locale} />
        </StaticRouter>
    )

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        walker(routing, (element, instance) => {
            if (instance && typeof instance._prepare == typeof (() => {}))
                return instance._prepare()
        }).then(() => {
            html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(routing)
            head = Helmet.renderStatic()
            template = _template.replace(/\${__rh-([a-z]+)}/gi, (match, group) => {
                return head[group].toString()
            })
            template = template.replace(/\${__body}/gi, (match) => {
                return html
            })
            if (context.url)
                context["statusCode"] = 301

            resolve({
                statusCode: context["statusCode"] || 200, 
                template, 
                redirect: context.url
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            template = _template.replace(/\${__rh-([a-z]+)}/gi, "")
            template = template.replace(/\${__body}/gi, error.stack || error.toString())
            resolve({
                statusCode: 500, 
                template
            })
        })
    })
}

var app = express()

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    var accepted = req.acceptsLanguages()
    var locale = accepted ? (accepted[0] || "ru").split("-")[0] : "ru"
    run(req.originalUrl, locale).then((data) => {
        if (data.redirect)
            res.redirect(data.redirect)
        else
            res.status(data.statusCode).send(data.template)
    })
})

app.listen(1239)
```

You can see that the `react-tree-walker` is used here. But this problem occurs whatever I'm using for the server-side render.

The problem is that if my `node-js` server is running in one thread, then if two different requests are being done simultaneously, then `react-helmet` mixes fields. For example, if there are two views:

```js
class FirstView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Helmet>
                <title>This is first title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="My first view description" />
            </Helmet>
        )
    }
}
```

and

```js
class SecondView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Helmet>
                <title>This is second title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="My second view description" />
            </Helmet>
        )
    }
}
```

then I can receive the head something like that:

```html
<title>This is first title</title>
<meta name="description" content="My second view description" />
```

Obviously this happens because of `react-helmet` uses static fields, I suppose. So, if two requests are being handled in parallel, this fields are being changed chaoticaly.

How can I defeat it? This problem often occurs for high-load projects, and this can crash the SEO, because crawler can receive wrong data.

---

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require("webpack")

var config = {
    mode: "production",
    target: "node",
    entry: __dirname + "/index.tsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: `index.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve("phoenix"),
                use: "imports-loader?window=>global"
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader?configFileName=tsconfig.server.json",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|png|jpg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|sass)$/,
                loader: "ignore-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            "node_modules",
            `${__dirname}/../src`
        ],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".sass", ".json", ".css", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    parallelism: 2,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "ENV": JSON.stringify("server"),
            "process.env.ENV": JSON.stringify("server"),
            "process.env.VERSION": JSON.stringify("n/a"),
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production"),
            "global.GENTLY": false
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = config
```

---

## Edit

Seems like, `react-helmet` is **thread-unsafe** according to [this issue](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/216). Is there any possibility to create some workaround based on this knowlenge?

Comment: are `FirstView` and `SecondView` on different routes?

Comment: @GauravSaraswat yes, of course

Comment: i doubt `require(`../dist/${version.v()}/index.html`)` gives you a string object which modifies the content of  exported `/index.html`. can you tell me which loader are you using to require `.html` files

Comment: @GauravSaraswat oh, I think I'm starting to understand what the trick. I have updated my question with the `webpack.config.js` (I use `html-loader`)

Comment: I dont think, that should create any problem. `can you try to just require the html file only once at top with imports` `instead of again and again in run function` and `assign it to template private variable inside the promise returned in run function`

Comment: does that help?

Comment: @GauravSaraswat I'm sorry, I'm unable to test it now. I will tell you when it will be checked :) but my 6th sense tells me that you are right

Comment: sure. I just updated my answer below. lemme know if it worked :)

Answer (score 6):

I feels `require(../dist/${version.v()}/index.html);` imports only one instance of the template.

By requiring the template repeatedly in all network calls you might be updating the same string reference again and again.

so. You can do the following:

1. `import(require) template` **only once** at the top of your file.
2. assign it to new variable of string type inside the promise returned in the run function and perform replace operations over it.

basic code snippet:

```js
...
import version = require("../version");

import appTemplate = require(`../dist/${version.v()}/index.html`)


interface IRenderResponse {
    statusCode: number,
    template: string,
    redirect?: string
}

const run = (url: string, locale?: string): Promise<IRenderResponse> => {
    var template: string = "";
    var html: string = ""
    var head: object
    var context: StaticRouterContext = {}

    useStaticRendering(true)

    var routing = (
        <StaticRouter 
            location={url} 
            context={context}
        >
            <Provider defaultLocale={locale} />
        </StaticRouter>
    )

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        walker(routing, (element, instance) => {
            if (instance && typeof instance._prepare == typeof (() => {}))
                return instance._prepare()
        }).then(() => {
            html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(routing)
            head = Helmet.renderStatic()
            template = appTemplate.replace(/\${__rh-([a-z]+)}/gi, (match, group) => {
                return head[group].toString()
            })
            template = template.replace(/\${__body}/gi, (match) => {
                return html
            })
            if (context.url)
                context["statusCode"] = 301

            resolve({
                statusCode: context["statusCode"] || 200, 
                template, 
                redirect: context.url
            })
        })....
```

Comment: FInally I have checked this out, and it is not working.
And I think, that there is no trick in import or something. `appTemplate` is being imported, so `webpack` loads it as a string during compilation. No filesystem operaions are being executed during `run()`. But fields are still mixing. I think, that problem is exactly in `react-helmet`

Comment: And, yes, [`react-helmet` is thread-unsafe](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/216)